# Removing double spaces

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have trouble solving this. I want to create a plot with the count of every punctuation signs(; - . ,).
I have this code

```
wekto<-c("Robot, robot; Nose, nose; Robot, robot; Toes, toes; Robot, robot - touch your nose. Robot, robot - touch your toes.")
stops <- function(text){
    wekto%>%
      str_remove_all("[A-z]") %>%
        str_split(pattern = " ") %>%
            table() %>%
              as.data.frame %>%
                setNames(c("Punctuation","Count"))%>%
                  ggplot(aes(x=Punctuation,y=Count)) +
                    geom_col() +
                      coord_flip()+
                        theme_classic()+
                          theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 17))
}
```

**But i want it to show it without the spaces, which are added to my data frame because of double spaces.**
How can i remove them?
I tried it with `str_remove` and `str_replace` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this by inserting the following code into your pipe chain after `setNames`:

```
subset(Punctuation != "")
```

Or considering adding space to your regular expression:

```
str_remove_all("[A-z\\s]") %>% 
  str_split("")
```

However, I would also caution against using a case-mixture regular expression like `A-z`. You will end up including more characters than you think: [Ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

You might want to consider `A-Za-z` or a character class such as `\\w` or `[:punct:]`:

```
gsub("[^[:punct:]]+", "", wekto) %>% 
  str_split("") %>% 
  table(dnn = "Punctuation") %>% 
  as.data.frame(responseName = "Count") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Punctuation,y=Count)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 17))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that really helped! And thank you for the advice :)